# Home Network Topology performance with CCTV

Tags: networking, router, performance, cctv

My home network is evolving over time and is starting to get a little messy. I have added a set of CCTV cameras and a new POE switch and am using my Synology NAS DS916+ as the NVR (Surveillance Station). The NAS also is used for important photo and document backup on the home network.

Below you will see my attempt at a network digram of my house originally, currently and proposed. I have added cameras into the seperate POE switch (TP-SG to power them however the data is flowing back to the NAS drive through the original switch (TP-SG101DE). There will be quite a lot of data constantly travelling through the two switches to get to the NAS unnessessarily. The photo and document backup doesn't happen that often whereas the CCTV recording is constant 24/7 and could impact network performance (especially when live viewing). My thoughts were to move the NAS either in entirety to the POE switch or unbond the link aggregation and split the network interfaces over both switches. This would allow me to segregate the CCTV traffic from the main home network switch (if it moves in entirety i would still need access to backup files somehow). I'm concerned that if a couple of rooms in the house are streaming high quality video and playing games and then the CCTV is also going there is going to be a performance drop.

Currently everything on both switches is on the same subnet 192.168.1.x and the router is acting as the DHCP server.

My goal is to get a simple, secure and performant network topology. Is my proposed solution sensible? Is there a better answer? Am I making a mountain out of a mole hill ?
[image]

Comment: Great job on describing the issue and kudos on all the hardwork with the network diagrams! I commend you for raising valid concerns and thinking critically. I would suggest that your biggest bottleneck for performance will be in 2 places: The NAS, or the Wifi. If your wired network is running at 1Gbps I don't believe you will see any impact on performance on that - so, reconfiguring the wired network would probably be considered a "mountain out of a mole hill." You can do some bandwidth calculations using online tools to put your mind at ease.

Comment: Well, let's start doing some bandwidth calculations. What's the video bitrate of those cameras? Just look it up on the spec sheet; you can't calculate it from the megapixels and frame rate because it will be compressed, and even if you know the compression algorithm there are usually lots of quality level adjustments tha affect the bitrate.

Comment: assume all 6 cameras are recording in H.265 variable bit rate with max set to 5120.

Comment: I suppose part of this question is about me not understanding how switches segregate network traffic and whether data flowing across the switch will affect all data on it.

Comment: @sarin 5120 bits per second is impossibly low. Did you mean 5120 Kbps? So a little over 5 Mbps max bitrate for each stream?

Comment: @Spiff yes yes. Kbps, although, after doing some reading, if I want to record at 4k I should be upping it to 16384 Kbps. So perhaps I should be using that figure instead. Go with 16384 Kbps.. Cheers for the help